# Remove characters from String which are contained in another String

Tags: java, string

I've written a method that is intended to remove characters from a string which are specified by another string.

I'll show you what I've written first so it becomes easier to comprehend my issue:

```
public static String removeFromInventory(String input, String inventory) {

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char character = input.charAt(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < inventory.length(); j++) {
            if (inventory.charAt(j) == character) {
                inventory = inventory.replace(character, ' ');
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (inventory.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            inventory = inventory.replaceAll("\\s+","");
        }
    }
    return inventory;
}
```

Imagine my input String looks like this: "11+" and my inventory String like this: "111234++". Now what I want to achieve is the following: I want to remove "11+" from the inventory string, so it looks like this afterwards: "11234+".

My code obviously removes any occurrence of the characters in the string. The the return statement looks like this after going through the function: "234".
If you know how I could implement some logic to only remove the first occurrence of the character I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Why does removing "11+" from "111234++" result in "11234+"?

Comment: "If you know how I could implement some logic to only remove the first occurrence of the character" ... well, there's `String.replaceFirst(regex, replacement)` for one. You could be more efficient though using `StringBuilder` along with `indexOf()` and `deleteCharAt()` etc. - However, representing some inventory as a string seems like a design error. I'm not sure whether order is relevant but a `Map<Character, Integer>` might be more appropriate (key to number of occurences - of course the value would be at least 1, i.e. you'd remove entries with a value of 0 or less).

Comment: Because I remove 2* "1" and 1* "+". I'm sure there are better ways to achieve the exact same thing.. But the reason I can't use a method like this is because I don't know what to replace the string with.. Only once I iterate over it I figure that out. Thanks though

Comment: You realize that your example was flawed, right? ;) - If you remove 2x 1 and 1x + from "111234++" it would result in "1234+" and not "11234+". "I don't know what to replace the string with" - I'm not sure what exactly you are referring to:  if you use your approach removing stuff would mean replacing matches with an empty string, if you're referring to my `Map<Character, Integer>` suggestion: replace the string with that map where the chars in the string are the keys and the number of occurrences are the values.

Answer (score 3):

Solution 1:
The function iterates through each character of the "input" string in a loop and utilizes the String.replaceFirst() method and a regular expression pattern constructed with Pattern.quote to replace the "+" has a special meaning in regex, so it needs to be escaped/quoted. The function's output is then the resultant "inventory" string without the given characters. By doing this, it will eliminate every occurrence of the characters from the inventory string. As anticipated, the final result is "1234+".

```
  public static String removeChars(String input, String inventory) {

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
        inventory = inventory.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(String.valueOf(input.charAt(i))), "");
    return inventory;
}
```

Solution 2:
The second solution is more optimized as it uses a HashMap to store the count of characters in the input, so it can handle the case of removing characters in input multiple times. It also uses StringBuilder for building the final string, which is more efficient than concatenating strings.

```
    public static  String removeCharacters(String input, String inventory){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    HashMap<Character, Integer> inputCount = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        char c = input.charAt(i);
        inputCount.put(c, inputCount.getOrDefault(c, 0) + 1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < inventory.length(); i++) {
        char c = inventory.charAt(i);
        if (!inputCount.containsKey(c) || inputCount.get(c) == 0) {
            sb.append(c);
        } else {
            inputCount.put(c, inputCount.get(c) - 1);
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Note: that `if (String.valueOf(input.charAt(i)).equals("+"))` in your first snippet isn't necessary as you could always do `inventory.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote(String.valueOf(input.charAt(i))), "");`. In your second snippet you could replace `if (!inputCount.containsKey(c) || inputCount.get(c) == 0)` with `Integer count = inputCount.get(c); if( count == null || count == 0)` - one lookup less :)

Comment: @thomas Hi Thomas, good suggestion but you see I am using replaceFirst method in the else block that replaces the first occurring character with an empty string it uses regex but it does not work with the '+' character so I am using the substring

Comment: That's the point: `+` has a special meaning in regex so it needs to be escaped/quoted. That's what `Pattern.quote(...)` is doing.

Comment: @thomas thank you for pointing that out, I will optimize my answer

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for the method says
"Returns a string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar."
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,char)

substring would be an OK replacement if used like this.

```
    for (int j = 0; j < inventory.length(); j++) {
        if (inventory.charAt(j) == character) {
            inventory = inventory.substring(0,j) + ' ' + inventory.substring(j+1);
            break;
        }
    }
```